# how to import multiple JSON data into table using ng-Tables

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ngtable

I am using ng-table for AngularJS and i am using single JSON file for the table data. i want to import multiple JSON files into a single table. I am able to import single JSON file using this code below.

Thank you in advance.

HTML

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table ng-table-responsive">
                <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                    <td data-title="'ID'" sortable="'ID'">
                        {{user.ID}}
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'Name'" filter="{ 'name': 'Name' }">
                        {{user.Name}}
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'Email'" sortable="'email'">
                        {{user.email}}
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'Address'" sortable="'address'">
                        {{user.address}}
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'PersonalEmail'" sortable="'personalemail'">
                        {{user.personalemail}}
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'PhoneNo'" sortable="'phoneno'">
                        {{user.phoneno}}
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'Status'" sortable="'status'">
                        {{user.status}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams, NameService) {

    var data = NameService.data;

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
      {
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,           // count per page
        sorting: {name:'asc'}
      },
      {
        total: 0, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
          NameService.getData($defer,params,$scope.filter);
        }
    });

    $scope.$watch("filter.$", function () {
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
    });

});

app.service("NameService", function($http, $filter){

  function filterData(data, filter){
    return $filter('filter')(data, filter)
  }

  function orderData(data, params){
    return params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;
  }

  function sliceData(data, params){
    return data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count())
  }

  function transformData(data,filter,params){
    return sliceData( orderData( filterData(data,filter), params ), params);
  }

  var service = {
    cachedData:[],
    getData:function($defer, params, filter){
      if(service.cachedData.length>0){
        console.log("using cached data")
        var filteredData = filterData(service.cachedData,filter);
        var transformedData = sliceData(orderData(filteredData,params),params);
        params.total(filteredData.length)
        $defer.resolve(transformedData);
      }
      else{
        console.log("fetching data")
        $http.get("json/1.json").success(function(resp)
        {
          angular.copy(resp,service.cachedData)
          params.total(resp.length)
          var filteredData = $filter('filter')(resp, filter);
          var transformedData = transformData(resp,filter,params)

          $defer.resolve(transformedData);
        });  
      }

    }
  };
  return service;  
});
```

Comment: merge the data in an array and then display it in ngtable

Comment: no, the thing is i want data from separate multiple JSON files

Comment: Right, and he's saying that in order to do that you'll need to merge the data from the separate JSON files into one array and then display it. If you can load one you can load multiple JSONs and then it's just a matter of combining the Arrays.

http://davidwalsh.name/combining-js-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve all your JSON content with [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and merge your arrays in the callback. Finally pass the resulting array to ng-table.